# Hide a row in List when the row doesn't contain any data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a list with 4 rows, each row contains different tables. I have filters and visibility for each table, but the list is showing empty row and space even if it doesn't satisfy the filter and visibility condition.

I need to hide the row in List when the row doesn't contain any data.

```
IIF((hide the row), true, false)
```

Comment: can you show what you mean by this? Is the data from a single dataset or multiple datasets for each table?

Comment: Hide a row in list, if it is empty

Comment: Same dataset that is single dataset

Comment: with out the context of what you are trying to achieve, it's hard to give an answer.. why do you have 4 tables for e.g. from a single data set.. There must be a criteria for the table to show data in that table right? Use the same criteria to set the visibility on each row.. something like =iif(isnothing (sum(somefiled.value,"your_dataset")),true,false)

Answer (score 0):

Alright Try something like this.
For Ex: Your each Row has a specific column let's say Product ID or Account ID or similar.

Use this as a Row Visibility Expression

```
IIF(Isnothing(Fields!MyId.Value),true,false)
```

OR you could also do something like below if you do not have any Particular Column which always will contain Data.

```
IIF(Isnothing(Fields!MyId.Value,Fields!MySecondField.Value,Fields!MyThirdField.Value),true,false)
```